# Ubuntu user account keeps getting locked out / password rejected

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, passwords, user-accounts, administrator

I am administering an Ubuntu 18.04 computer. Recently, I made an account for a new user with sudo privileges using `useradd`, with a password. The new user was able to ssh into the account without problems for several days, but reported suddenly getting locked out (ssh would no longer accept the password, even though it was correct and he did not change it). I deleted the user account and made another account for them with the same commands/password; again this worked for 2-3 days before the same problem occurred. We've gone through this cycle several times now, and I'm completely stumped as to what can be causing this issue. How can I get to the root of the problem?

Comment: (1) What was the reason to create the account anew instead of `sudo passwd user`? (2) You know their password and allegedly they did not change it. Have you tried `su user`? `su - user`? `sudo -iu user`? `ssh -v user@localhost`? // My point is *maybe* the password was/is right all the time; maybe they keep breaking their startup scripts and this locks them out. By deleting the old account you deleted the broken script.

Comment: The first time I tried, the password was rejected from me as well. Admittedly the subsequent times I didn't try to change it and will try next time. Which startup scripts are you referring to, `.bashrc`? How would they break it?

Comment: I'm referring to the script(s) specific to their shell. They can break a script e.g. [by adding `exit`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610894/108618).

Comment: I will look for that if it happens again. I don't think they would have done that on purpose, unless it's done automatically from installing something. Not sure how else it could have happened. What I had thought was maybe it was triggered by a security locking mechanism related to incorrect password attempts or something like that.